# Unboxing - Recording voice when there's other louder noises (cutting, ripping)

Tags: voice, background, youtube

So I often film unboxing and teardown videos for Youtube, and have so many issues with recording my voice clearly. Typically the waveform I get has severe peaks due to noises when cutting/ripping/opening packages, or dropping tools, etc, which make amplifying my voice difficult as it's stuck in between these peaks. I'm guessing all I can do to stop this is speak more closely and directly into the Microphone and try to reduce 'unboxing noise', but any other tips or secrets you guys have would be appreciated! I have a Blue Yeti mic set to condenser, and can't always speak directly into it, or at least I often forget which is probably the main issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Context is king here. If you are seeing your mouth and the unboxing action, then you need to hear both.

If we are only seeing the unboxing action, then you record only the sound of the unboxing action (with the vision) and to the dialogue as a voiceover. This way, you will have much more control over the relative levels.

Don't try and use something like a yeti, you will best be served by a headset mic or a lavalier. The closer to your mouth the capsule is, the better the ratio of dialogue to production effects will be.

Comment: I think you're right, I need a headset mic or lavalier for my voice, so it's always close to my mouth. Thanks Mark, and have a great Christmas and New Years :)

Answer (score 2):

Along with marks answer, without knowing the setup, if you have a cardioid pickup pattern and place the item behind the microphone then it can reduce the noise a good amount. Also using a compressor can lower the quick spikes in volume.